# Problema com Insert e PDO

Tags: php, pdo, sql-insert

Estou tentando fazer um insert com PDO. Para isso utilizo:

**controller/con_clientes.add.php**

```
<?php
if($action == "new_client"){
    $search_cod_cliente = $pdo->prepare("SELECT MAX(cli_cod_cliente) AS cli_cod_cliente FROM clients"); 
    $search_cod_cliente->execute();

    while($result_cod_cliente = $search_cod_cliente->fetchObject()){
        $cli_cod_cliente = $result_cod_cliente->cli_cod_cliente + 1;
    }

    $conectar = new Con_Clients_Add;
    $conectar = $conectar->con_clients_add($cli_cod_cliente);
}
?>
```

**classes/Con_Clients_Add.class.php**

```
<?php
    class Con_Clients_Add{
        public function con_clients_add($cli_cod_cliente){
            try {
                $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$database, $login_db, $senha_db);
                $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
            }

            $client_insert = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO clients(cli_cod_cliente) VALUES (:cli_cod_cliente)");
            $client_insert->bindParam(':cli_cod_cliente', $cli_cod_cliente, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $client_insert->execute(); 
        }
    }
?>
```

Porém se utilizo o método tradicional, funciona:

```
$db = mysql_connect ($host, $login_db, $senha_db);
$basedados = mysql_select_db($database);

$insere_cliente = mysql_query("INSERT INTO clients(cli_cod_cliente) VALUES ('$cli_cod_cliente')");
```

Obrigado pela força.
Abraços.
Rafael

Comment: Algum erro? O que acontece?

Comment: Pois é... Aparece erro 500

Comment: Isto `echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();` não acontece?

Comment: Não... O engraçado é que a variável $cli_cod_cliente vem do controller/con_clients_add.php... Mas se eu forço um valor, por exemplo: $cli_cod_cliente = '1900'; aí funciona...

Comment: Estou duvidando que tem a ver com isso...
$client_insert->bindParam(':cli_cod_cliente', $cli_cod_cliente, PDO::PARAM_STR);

Comment: Eu só acho estranho porque não parece ter a ver com a conecção, senão imprimia `'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();`

Comment: Coloca isso no início do seu script, deve mostrar os erros: `ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Answer (score 1):

O problema parece ser que o seu método `con_clients_add` está sendo interpretado como constutor da classe, então na primeira chamada.

Um método com o mesmo nome da classe em algumas circustancias é considera como construtor.

O ideal é definir o construtor como `__construct()` ou mudar o nome do seu método.

```
$conectar = new Con_Clients_Add; //primeira chamada
$conectar = $conectar->con_clients_add($cli_cod_cliente); segunda chamada
```

Exemplo simples

```
class abc{
    public function abc(){
        echo 'sou o construtor<br>';
    }
}

$a = new abc();
$a->abc();
```

Saida:

```
sou o construtor
sou o construtor
```

Comment: Resolvido... Alterei o nome do método e deu certo. Obrigado.

Se eu desejar utilizar o __construct(), como seria?

Comment: @Miguel a conexão pode se feita com sucesso, ok, mas a consulta pode falhar pq o id é vazio. Podar dar o warning `Missing argument 1 for`

Comment: Mas o insert chega a acontecer? Tinha a sensação que não. @RafaelSchafferGimenes deves aceitar a resposta, por baixo das setas cima/baixo à esquerda da resposta, bem-vindo

Comment: @Miguel acho que não, como não tem nenhum `try` para ele vc nem fica sabendo se deu certo ou não, no maximo um "olha tem uma exceção não capturada ai"

Comment: Ha que estupidez a minha, a conecção estava a ser feita claro o insert é que não, correto?

Comment: @Miguel isso, não primeira nem funciona só gera warnings, já segunda sim pq `$cli_cod_cliente` foi definida e tem valor.